# Excluding markup on lowercased parentheses letters

Tags: java, regex

A string can contain one to many parentheses in lower case letters like `String content = "This is (a) nightmare";` I want to transform the string to `"<centamp>This is </centamp>(a) <centamp>nightmare</centamp>";` So basically add centamp markup around this string but if it has a lowercase letter in parentheses that should be excluded from the markup.

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't achieve the desired result. There could be none to many parentheses in a string and excluding it from the markup should happen for every parentheses.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)?(\\([a-z]*\\))?(.*)?$", Pattern.MULTILINE);    
String content = "This is (a) nightmare";
System.out.println(content.matches("^(.*)?(\\([a-z]*\\))?(.*)?$"));
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("&lt;centamp&gt;$1$3&lt;/centamp&gt;$2"));
```

Comment: I would *split* on `(a)` and then surround each non-empty part with `<centamp>..</centamp>`. It's much easier for me to think/reason about by dividing it into different steps.

Comment: I cannot control that. I'm using an api ..

Comment: @Phoenix: Given that you can write code, I think that suggestion is feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one `replaceAll`:

```
String outputString =
    inputString.replaceAll("(?s)\\G((?:\\([a-z]+\\))*+)((?:(?!\\([a-z]+\\)).)+)",
                           "$1<centamp>$2</centamp>");
```

It allows a **non-empty** sequence of lower case English alphabet character inside bracket `\\([a-z]+\\)`.

Features:

- Whitespace only sequences are tagged.
- There will be no tag surrounding empty string.

Explanation:

- `\G` asserts the match boundary, i.e. the next match can only start from the end of last match. It can also match the beginning of the string (when we have yet to find any match).
- Each match of the regex will contain a sequence of: 0 or more consecutive `\\([a-z]+\\)` (no space between allowed), and followed by at least 1 character that does not form `\\([a-z]+\\)` sequence.

  - 0 or more consecutive `\\([a-z]+\\)` to cover the case where the string does not start with `\\([a-z]+\\)`, and the case where the string does not contain `\\([a-z]+\\)`.

    In the pattern for this portion `(?:\\([a-z]+\\))*+` - note that the `+` after `*` makes the quantifier *possessive*, in other words, it disallows backtracking. Simply put, an optimization.
  - One character restriction is necessary to prevent adding tag that encloses empty string.

    In the pattern for this portion `(?:(?!\\([a-z]+\\)).)+` - note that for every character, I check whether it is part of the pattern `\\([a-z]+\\)` before matching it `(?!\\([a-z]+\\)).`.
- `(?s)` flag will cause `.` to match any character including new line. This will allow a tag to enclose text that spans multiple lines.

Comment: Why do you need to have 2 ((?:\\([a-z]+\\))*+)((?:(?!\\([a-z]+\\)) of them ?

Comment: @Phoenix: They are not the same. The first portion `((?:\([a-z]+\))*+)` matches a sequence such as `(a)(b)`, the second portion `(?:(?!\\([a-z]+\\)).)+` matches text that does not contain lowercase in parentheses, such as `random text`

Comment: Why doesn't this work on a string like  String content = "Addendum Seven.&emsp;Regulations of the United States Court of Appeals for the Eleventh Circuit for the Selection and Appointment or (don't centamp me) the Reappointment of Federal Public Defenders";
I want the content in the parentheses to be outside the brackets ..

Comment: @Phoenix: Because you said that you only want to allow lower case characters. Space and `'` are not lower case characters, so they are `centamp`.

Answer (score 1):

You just replace all of the occurence of "([a-z])" with </centamp>$1<centamp> and then prepend <centamp> and append </centamp>

```
String content = "Test (a) test (b) (c)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\([a-z]\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
String result = "&lt;centamp&gt;" + matcher.replaceAll("&lt;/centamp&gt;$1&lt;centamp&gt;") + "&lt;/centamp&gt;";
```

**note** I wrote the above in the browser so there may be syntax errors.

**EDIT** Here's a full example with the simplest RegEx possible.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String content = "test (a) (b) and (c)";
        String result = "<centamp>" + 
            content.replaceAll("(\\([a-z]\\))", "</centamp>$1<centamp>") +
            "</centamp>";
        result = result.replaceAll("<centamp></centamp>", "");
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is right .. because it doesnt work for "(a)"

Comment: @Phoenix - if by "doesnt work" you mean there is extra markup then yes that's true, you can remove unnecessary markup with another replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution which uses cleaner regex. The solution is longer, but it allows more flexibility in adjusting the condition to add tag.

The idea here is to match the parenthesis containing lower case characters (the part we don't want to tag), then use the indices from the matches to identify the portion we want to enclose in tag.

```
// Regex for the parenthesis containing only lowercase English
// alphabet characters
static Pattern REGEX_IN_PARENTHESIS = Pattern.compile("\\([a-z]+\\)");

private static String addTag(String str) {
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_IN_PARENTHESIS.matcher(str);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Index that we have processed up to last append into StringBuilder
    int lastAppend = 0;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String bracket = matcher.group();

        // The string from lastAppend to start of a match is the part
        // we want to tag
        // If you want to, you can easily add extra logic to process
        // the string
        if (lastAppend < matcher.start()) { // will not tag if empty string
            sb.append("<centamp>")
              .append(str, lastAppend, matcher.start())
              .append("</centamp>");
        }

        // Append the parenthesis with lowercase English alphabet as it is
        sb.append(bracket);

        lastAppend = matcher.end();
    }

    // The string from lastAppend to end of string (no more match)
    // is the part we want to tag
    if (lastAppend < str.length()) {
        sb.append("<centamp>")
          .append(str, lastAppend, str.length())
          .append("</centamp>");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```